# Jquery Explanation >*

Tags: jquery

I was going through a p rewritten jQuery code . I'm not able to understand the following code .

```
$('body > *:not(#print-modal):not(script)').clone();
```

Comment: not totally sure of the syntax either, but it looks to me like it would clone every element in body which isn't a script element and doesn't have id = print-modal

Comment: @PhillipSchmidt: Only direct children (that's what `>` does) :-P

Comment: @Rocket thanks! never actually used it lol

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This selector matches any tag that is:

- A direct child of `<body>`
- Does not have the ID `print-modal` and
- Is not a `<script>` tag.

It then clones all these elements with `.clone()`, although nothing is done with the `clone()`d object, which is strange.

A more in-depth explanation:

`body > *` means "select all elements that are direct descendants of `<body>`", the wildcard `*` selecting every tag. Next, the two [`:not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) pseudo-classes filter remove the element with the ID `print_modal`, as well as any `<script>` tags.

Reference:

- [jQuery's `:not()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)
- [Child and sibling CSS selectors](http://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/) (and another link on the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Child_selectors))
- [Universal CSS selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Universal_selectors)

Comment: Thank you, @rocket, I didn't even see that.

Comment: "direct child" is redundant .. `>` is called the "child selector" (CSS terminology, but jQuery should use the same).  If it's not direct, it's a "descendant."

Comment: @Explosion Very true, however I thought it would be best to be as explicit as possible to reduce any confusion that may be caused.

Comment: fair enough, but I would like to encourage everyone to use the standard terminology .. then there's no need to be explicit.

Comment: It's required to make a valid selector.

Comment: @JamWaffles I hate to rain on your parade (again), but no it's not: http://jsfiddle.net/sAdjt/

Answer (score 2):

If I am correct, in this case `>*` is a selector for all children of the `body` tag, with `:not(#print-modal)` and `:not(script)` providing two exclusions from the selector.

Answer (score 1):

`>` means "direct chidren of".

`*` means "any tag".

So, this is saying find any tags (that aren't `<script>` or have `id="print-modal"`) that are 1st level children of `<body>`.

Note: the `*` is not needed here as `:not` will assume the `*` if there is nothing before it.

Answer (score 0):

It selects all elements that are direct children of the body that are not script tags and do not have the id `print-modal`.

`*` in a jQuery selector means all elements.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('body > *:not(#print-modal):not(script)').clone();
```

means that, clone all immediate child elements of body but not any element with id `print-modal` and not `script` tags.

**It could be also written as**

```
$('body > *').not('#print-modal, script').clone();
```

**Reference:** [**jQuery**](http://api.jquery.com/not/).

Comment: or `$('body').children().not(...`

Comment: Yes but I think `>*` is shorter than `children()`.

Comment: Character-wise maybe, however which one executes faster? But it really doesn't matter unless you are dealing with the mobile market.